# Android custom phone dialer

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to redesign the look and feel of my phone and right now i'm redoing the phone app. From searching over stackoverflow and other QA sites I understand that to make a phone call I can use this code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:000000000")); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

But this code only asks the system to perform the call, so immediately after startActivity, the phone stock ui comes up and performs the call.

Also I read some people saying that you cannot bypass the dial screen, that this is a security measure implemented by Google. So I was just wondering if indeed it is impossible to make a fully fledged phone dialler or if there is a way, thanks!

Comment: I also want to make a customized dialer for my app.Have you found the solution to your question?

Comment: No i didn't, sorry :/

Comment: After tinkering a bit I was able to show a view ontop of the Dialer app whenever its launched(and hence customize the look of the native dialer app).For more see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701879/popup-window-on-incoming-call-screen-like-truecaller/24377603#24377603